# Having difficulty in figuring how the anonymous function is called to alert('B!')

Tags: javascript

Found this code and if someone could take the time to tell me how alert('B!') is called in this scenario, it would be very appreciated. An please explain in newbie terms, thank you.

```
function a() {
alert('A!');
return function(){
alert('B!');
};
}

a = a();
a();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have `a = a();` which means "execute function `a` and store any returned value back into `a`. In this case, the "returned value" is a defined function. In Javascript (and plenty of other scripting languages), you can store functions in variables without actually executing them so that you can execute them later. Then, in the following line of code, we have `a();` which is executing the function we returned in the previous line of code, which has the `alert('B!');` line as part of the function body.

To help illustrate, try the following:

```
var a = function() {
    alert('Testing!');
};

a();
```

Despite not defining the function like...

```
function someFun() {
    alert('Testing!');
}
```

...we're still able to make calls to the function.

Look into `callback` and `anonymous` functions in particular. They're very prevalent in Javascript and incredibly useful as well!

Comment: Thank you B. Fleming, I am blind as a bat sometimes, appreciate the help.